# Ember js observers and computed properties in typescript

Tags: javascript, ember.js, typescript, ember-data, typescript1.4

How can I define emberjs observers and computed properties using typescript?

I need to write the following code in typescript.

```
module App {
App.UserController = ember.ObjectController.extend({
    firstName: "John",
    lastName: "Doe",
    fullName: function() {
       return this.get("firstName") + " " + this.get("lastName");
    }.property("firstName", "lastName")
});
}
```

Something like:

```
class UserController extends ember.ObjectController {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.firstName = "John";
        this.lastName = "Doe";
    }

    get fullName(): string {
        return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
    }.property("firstName", "lastName")
}
```

But this doesnt seem to work. Can someone tell me the correct way to do this without using javascript?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a version of your code that will compile:

```
module App {

    export var UserController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
        firstName: "John",
        lastName: "Doe",
        fullName: function () {
            return this.get("firstName") + " " + this.get("lastName");
        }.property('model.isCompleted')
    });
}

// Example:
var x = App.UserController;
```

Update

You can implement this with a class, here is an example that compiles:

```
class UserController extends Ember.ObjectController {
    private firstName: string;
    private lastName: string;

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.firstName = "John";
        this.lastName = "Doe";
    }

    get fullName(): string {
        return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
    }
}

var x = new UserController();

console.log(JSON.stringify(x));
```

Comment: But this is still javascript. I was looking for a solution which uses pure typeScript.

Comment: When using some libraries, it is not possible to extend the objects in the library (if they haven't been written with this in mind). I believe Ember ObjectController objects are usable, so you can extend them using a TypeScript class. Example added.